# How to make bookmarks appear first in the GNOME files left pane?

Tags: gnome, gnome3

I have a dual boot Debian system with windows partitions. I never use and access those partitions from within Linux. But they appear first in the gnome files program. There are 4 disks shown in the left pane of the `gnome files` program which I never use: `HP_TOOLS`, `Recovery Image`, `Windows`, and `Windows RE tools`. How can I move all these to the bottom of the pane. So that my bookmarks appear first?

Comment: The order in the side pane is defined in nautilus source code. I don't think you can move groups of items (e.g. bookmarks, filesystems, user dirs etc) up or down. You could however [hide](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1231) those partitions as you don't use them anyway...

Comment: Thanks I used the gnome-disk-utility to `edit mount options`. Where I deselected  `Automatic mount option`, `mount at startup` and `show in user interface`.

Comment: yep, that is yet another way to hide them (it involves editing `/etc/fstab` and adding `x-gvfs-hide` etc).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the placement question but solves my issue by hiding the unnecessary partitions from the left menu.

Use the gnome-disk-utility to edit mount options. Then deselect `Automatic mount option`, `mount at startup` and `show in user interface`.